# How to import Objective-C classes into Console App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, console-application

Step 1. Create a simple console app in Xcode

Step 2. Create simple objective C class in same project

Step 3. Try to import like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why won't this compile? Xcode error is "too many errors emitted stopping now"

Comment: Well, it's most likely in the `//insert code here...` portion. But, if not, I would imagine it's because, to my knowledge, Xcode isn't set up to automatically handle these apps. Try running in via the Terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your source file is a C module. Change the extension to .m. Better yet, start with the Foundation-based tool project template in Xcode.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by changing extension to m, but starting with Foundation based tool template certainly works. Thanks.